# Close a console aplication with a list and reopen on the same point of the list

Tags: c#

I have a problem with a code in C#. I need to execute a console application that reads values from a very long list. I need to be able to close the console application and when I reopen it, be able to know where it stop from that list, to continue from that point.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Save the state in a file, database, or some other form of persistent storage.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.